# How do I disable pressure sensitivity of my Wacom pen, for Windows 8.1 or at least for Powerpoint 2013?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-powerpoint

I know pressure sensitivity for Wacom pens is a feature, but I would like to deactivate it:

[image: Wacom pressure sensitivity test]

**Is there any way to** set the pen to work in a digital fashion, i.e. **producing a fixed-width line**?  This is what the result would look like:

[image: Simulated mode I want - without pressure sensitivity]

In the "Wacom Pen" module in the Control Panel, I can select the general tip sensitivity, but I don't see an option to modify the pressure sensitivity:

[image: Wacom Pen settings dialog box]

In particular in Microsoft PowerPoint 2013, but a solution that disables pressure sensitivity in Windows 8.1 in general would be fine for me.

Comment: hit the calibrate button - you can overkill the sensitivity, if the app you're using doesn't have a simple on/off switch

Comment: @Tetsujin, what do you mean by "overkill the sensitivity"? The Calibrate button IMHO only lets me calibrate x-y, but not sensitivity. In Powerpoint, I have not found an option to disable sensitivity, that would also be part of my question.

Comment: I can no longer test it on mine, as it's so old the control panel won't launch, but there was a sensitivity option in the calibration, so you could adjust what was determined to be 'soft' or 'hard' pressure. If you 'fake' it so it reads everything as 'hard' then you've effectively disabled the sensitivity. Apps like Photoshop simply have an on/off switch for pressure - I've never used Powerpoint so idk if one exists there.

Comment: I haven't seen such a switch in PowerPoint, and I just verified that in my driver version the Calibrate button does not have a sensitivity option :-(. Thanks anyhow for the suggestion!

Comment: A bit of googling around your problem, and so many people have the opposite problem that pressure sensitivity doesn't work. Maybe something that fixes it for them could be done in reverse to break pressure sensitivity for you? Maybe using a specific driver version with known issues or disabling the Windows Pen & Tablet service.

Answer (score 1):

Drag the slider in the "Eraser" section all the way down to "Soft". On Mac, this section is called "Tip Feel".